Cannot update Digital Ocean Droplet, Perforce cannot retrieve update
I'm trying to update my Droplet, but I keep running into the same error that I've not been able to solve.
When I run sudo apt-get update it gives me this error:
W: Failed to fetch http://package.perforce.com/apt/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG RandomString Perforce Software (Package Signing) <support+packaging@perforce.com>
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
W: Target Packages (release/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:58 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/perforce.list:1
W: Target Packages (release/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:58 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/perforce.list:1
W: Target Translations (release/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:58 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/perforce.list:1
W: Target CNF (release/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:58 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/perforce.list:1
W: Target CNF (release/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:58 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/perforce.list:1

I've tried to run a few different commands but I am quite new to Perforce and do not want to break my repo that I've been contributing towards for over a year.
apt update, upgrade both of these result in similar errors
I can't even run p4 info without getting this error:
Perforce client error:
        Connect to server failed; check $P4PORT.
        connect: 127.0.0.1:1666: Connection refused


Checkpoint/backup your server, then contact Perforce tech support.

@Samwise I cannot even call p4 info without an error, this is from the droplet console

Can you shell into the VM and do p4d -jc?

This a digital ocean droplet where you did your own install from scratch? And not the official perforce digital ocean image, right? It seems like it since you're on Ubuntu but just wanted to check since the upgrade will be different.

I wonder if the perforce signing key has been updated since your original install. Might be worth double checking that here: https://www.perforce.com/perforce-packages
